# How to do round up to a non-zero threshold

Tags: php

I need to round up a given price to a non-zero threshold, such as 9, 8, 3, or 5.

I have tried `round()`, `floor()`, `ceil()` method but did not get the result I need.

```php
function tax_roundup($number, $taxRate)
{
    $taxprice = ceil($number);
    $mod_10;
    $mod_5;
    $mod_3;
    $mod_8;
    switch ($taxRate) {
        case 3:
            $delta = 0.0000001;
            $mod_3 = $taxprice % 3;
            //$taxprice = $taxprice + $delta;
            return $taxprice + 3 - $mod_3;
            break;
        case 5:
            $mod_5 = $taxprice % 5;
            return $taxprice + 5 - $mod_5;
            break;
        case 8:
            $mod_8 = $taxprice % 8;
            return $taxprice + 8 - $mod_8;
            break;
        case 9:
            $mod_10 = $taxprice % 10;
            return $taxprice + 10 - $mod_10 - 1;
            break;
        default:
            $mod_10 = $taxprice % 10;
            return $taxprice + 10 - $mod_10 - 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

Examples for rounding up to 9 Euro:
**15,00** € will be **19**€
**17,25**€ will be **19**€
**1456,23**€ will be **1459,00**€
**19,01**€ will be **29,00**€

Comment: `9,8,3,5` <- that's not a number so it can't be rounded. Even the [NumberFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class is going to choke on that...

Comment: No i mean i use these numbers based on switch case user will enter only one number at a time not a comma sepreated.like in ```tax_roundup(1500,9)``` so case 9 will run and the given price 1500 will round up with 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add the difference between your “round-to” digit and 10 to your price (so 1 for 9, 2 for 8, …), then you divide by ten. ceil to round that value up to the next integer, multiple by ten again, and subtract the difference between 10 and “round-to” digit again:

```
$prices = [15, 17.25, 1456.23, 19.01];
$round_to = [9, 8, 3, 5];

foreach($round_to as $r) {
  foreach($prices as $price) {
    $rounded = ceil ( ( $price + 10 - $r ) / 10 ) * 10 - ( 10 - $r );
    echo $price . ' rounded up to next ' . $r . ' is '. $rounded . "\n";  
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
15 rounded up to next 9 is 19
17.25 rounded up to next 9 is 19
1456.23 rounded up to next 9 is 1459
19.01 rounded up to next 9 is 29

15 rounded up to next 8 is 18
17.25 rounded up to next 8 is 18
1456.23 rounded up to next 8 is 1458
19.01 rounded up to next 8 is 28

15 rounded up to next 3 is 23
17.25 rounded up to next 3 is 23
1456.23 rounded up to next 3 is 1463
19.01 rounded up to next 3 is 23

15 rounded up to next 5 is 15
17.25 rounded up to next 5 is 25
1456.23 rounded up to next 5 is 1465
19.01 rounded up to next 5 is 25
```